# Phoenix and Ecto field x in `join` does not exist in the model source in query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Sup,
i was working my way through my project and I have encountered weird problem. I was trying to join between to tables in PostgreSQL with following schemes:

```
defmodule Hangman.MasterCat do
  use Hangman.Web, :model

  schema "mastercats" do
    field :name, :string

    has_many :categories, Hangman.Category
  end

  ...

end
```

And second one:

```
defmodule Hangman.Category do
  use Hangman.Web, :model

  schema "categories" do
    field :name, :string

    has_many :words, Hangman.Word
    belongs_to :mastercats, Hangman.MasterCat
  end

  ...

end
```

And Action code:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
    query = from p in MasterCat,
      join: c in Category,
      on: c.mastercat_id == p.id,
      select: {p, c}

    a = Repo.all(query)
    render conn, "index.json", mastercats: a
end
```

Field "mastercat_id" was defined in migration file as reference to categories:

```
defmodule Hangman.Repo.Migrations.CreateCategories do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:categories) do
      add :name, :string
      add :mastercat_id, references(:mastercats)

      timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And Action returns following error:

```
web/controllers/mastercat_controller.ex:8: field `Hangman.Category.mastercat_id` in `join` does not exist in the model source in query:

from m in Hangman.MasterCat,
  join: c in Hangman.Category,
  on: c.mastercat_id == m.id,
  select: {m, c}
```

I'll more than appreciate any help.
Cheers,
Haito

https://github.com/Hajto/hangmanelixir

Comment: Shouldn't `belongs_to :mastercats, Hangman.MasterCat` be `belongs_to :mastercat, Hangman.MasterCat`?

Comment: Yea it works, after applying that change i had to restart server. But it renders now empty.